# Getting Permissions required by installed apps : Application Force Closes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to make an app which gives the list of installed apps and when an item is clicked , starts another activity which states the permissions required by installed apps.
I got the installed application list, but when I click any app instead of starting new activity , the application force closes.
I was following a [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/)

MainActivity

```
 package com.example.appslist;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.adapter.ApkAdapter;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ApkListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        ListView mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));



        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long row) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-02 11:16:04.536: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.559: D/dalvikvm(2777): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-02 11:16:04.559: I/dalvikvm(2777): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-02 11:16:04.567: E/MBGlossaryManager(2777): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-02 11:16:04.700: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-02 11:16:04.715: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.723: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-02 11:16:04.778: D/dalvikvm(2777): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 822 objects / 60704 bytes in 56ms
04-02 11:16:04.786: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.794: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.794: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.801: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.801: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.809: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.809: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calendar === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.825: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.825: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-02 11:16:04.872: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-02 11:16:06.536: D/AndroidRuntime(2777): Shutting down VM
04-02 11:16:06.536: W/dalvikvm(2777): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:44)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 11:16:08.137: I/Process(2777): Sending signal. PID: 2777 SIG: 9
```

Please help. Extremely sorry if the question is vague . I couldn't figure out and I am trying since a long time.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using List Activity. When you are using Activity your listview must have the id

set listview id in your xml

```
android:id="@android:id/list
```

And get it like this

```
ListView yorulistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks , I made the changes but still it is force closing on item click.

Comment: @Prax This is not your previous problem...Your previous problem is sovled..This is another problem you need to post another question for it. Because this question currently deals with the previous problem. And mark this answer cliking on the right mark beside the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and guidance , I am new to Stack Overflow. Thanks a lot :)